# Postgres db to snowflake migration

Tags: postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cdc

I want to migrate data from Amazon RDS postgres to snowflake with cdc on RDS table. Please let me know how can we do it.

Comment: question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

The question is too broad, but you should be able to do this following the step-by-step from AWS to stream CDC out of Postgres:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/stream-changes-from-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-using-amazon-kinesis-data-streams-and-aws-lambda/

And on the Snowflake side:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams.html

Or use a tool:

- https://www.striim.com/integrations/amazon-rds-for-postgresql-snowflake/

Please come back with specific questions once you've tried this and get stuck in specific steps. Create new Stack Overflow questions with as much detail and code as possible to reproduce.